# how can I log out from spotify from my application?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, authentication, spotify

I'm using this authentication via [implicit grant](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow)

So in my app, to log in to spotiffy I redirect to

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
```

while supplying `client_id`, `redirect_uri` and `response_type` as parameters

If not logged in, the GET request to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?params`  redirects me to the spotify login page.

Otherwise it responds with an access token.

Which leads me to this question: when I call https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?params when already logged in, and that it responds with a token, how does it know that I'm logged in being that I see nothing in my local storage?

And how can I reset the state of my browser to 'not logged in'?

Comment: Cookies? ... ... ...

Comment: No. I have nothing in cookies or local/session storage

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late but you can logout from spotify with this url [https://www.spotify.com/fr/logout](https://www.spotify.com/fr/logout/).
Or you can add `show_dialog=true` on your parameters of your redirect and it will ask the user everytime if he wants to autorize this app.